# React BrowserRouter Route is not working after deploy

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, routes

I have a simple website and have 2 links which is working offline but if i deploy it and upload it on a website then the first page is working fine but when i click on add Link then it's giving me 404 and list link is working fine and both link is working fine on offline

```
<a href="/react/">List</a>
<a href="/react/Add">Add</a>
```

Router file

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Route path="/react/" exact component={List}/>
    <Route path="/react/Add" exact component={Add}/>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Package.json

```
{
    "name": "axios1",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "homepage":"http://aroratour.com/react/",
```

Comment: Add some more code, like your routing and package.json file.

Comment: I had added my route and package file

Comment: Hi vivek, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: add switch and exact path  as refered down by @bahadur ,deploy and check again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have deployed your project in sub-folder called `react`. You need to add [`basename`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) to your `BrowserRouter` and need to remove `/react` from your `Route's` path,

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/react">
    <Switch> // Switch return the first matching Route
      <Route path="/" exact component={List}/>
      <Route path="/Add" exact component={Add}/>
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**Note:** Make sure to add `.htaccess` file.

If you have any `Link` in your project, that should not include `/react` in path.

For example, to navigate to `/Add` using `Link`, you should have,

```
<Link to="/Add"> Add </Link>
```

This will internally get's converted to,

```
<a href="/react/Add"> Add </a>   //React will automatically add `/react` from basename in BrowserRouter
```

---

**Update**

This `.htaccess` content works for me,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt|svg|woff|ttf|eot)$
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Comment: where i need to create .htaccess file inside react folder or outside?

Comment: i had write .htaccess file inside the react folder but still having same issue

Comment: Which server you are using?

Comment: i am using linux server

Comment: you can watch problem on aroratour.com/react

Comment: @vivekmodi, check the updated answer and try to use provided `.htaccess`.

Comment: should have to remove "/react" from homepage in package.json?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one more thing also use 'Switch' and 'exact path' instead of 'path'

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter basename="/react">
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/"  component={List}/>
       <Route exact path="/Add"  component={Add}/>
    </Switch>

</BrowserRouter>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Still having same issue

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy,you have to add .htaccess to hendal all routing request to index.html page.
create .htaccess in dist folder with below code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: still have same issue

Comment: can you share what result are you getting ?

Comment: i am getting 404 not found